# Universal in what sense?- The element 1 of the additive monoid of N

Tags: abstract-algebra

The additive monoid N of natural numbers is said to have a "universal" element, 1,
in the following sense: For any monoid M and any element, a, in it, there is 
exactly one morphism of monoids f:N  to  M, with f(1)= a.

Now how exactly is this universal? I take it that universal means "occurring in all monoids" and this refers to the property that for each a for any M there is only one morphism with f(1)=a. But it's still a bit unclear.

Please help, thanks :)

Comment: "Universal" does not mean "occurring in all monoids"; it means exactly what you wrote after "in the following sense".

Answer (score 0):

Anytime we have : x is such for all.. there exist one and only one something of (x) such that.. , we have defined an element by "universal property" (provided we have unicity of the element defined)
A good example is generalizing the cartesian product from Set to any category.

There is a more precise notion of "universal element" ( cf Leinster - basic category theory) which applies here as well though, in which actual universal element pertain to a functor X from C to Set, and is a *couple* A, x $\in$ XA  such that for all *couple* B, x $\in$ XB, $\exists ! x' : A \rightarrow B $  such that $(Xx') u = x$

In that case, the functor in question is the forgetful foncteur U, which takes a monoid to its underlying Set and forget all the arrows.

Then for every monoid M and element m in UM there is one unique arrow m' from N to M such that Um'(1)=m'